# Thread 1:EXC_ARITHMETIC(code=EXC_I386_DIV,subcode=0x0) in Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new to iOS programming. When I run my project I am getting thread error like:

> Thread 1:EXC_ARITHMETIC(code=EXC_I386_DIV,subcode=0x0)

I don't know how to solve that thread error. Can anyone suggest a solution for this problem?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSUInteger residue =  ([uiGridViewDelegate numberOfCellsOfGridView:self] % [uiGridViewDelegate numberOfColumnsOfGridView:self]);

    if (residue > 0) residue = 1;

    return ([uiGridViewDelegate numberOfCellsOfGridView:self] / [uiGridViewDelegate numberOfColumnsOfGridView:self]) + residue;
}
```

[image: I have attached the images]

Comment: Best way is add break point at starting of `numberOfRowsInSection` and print of value of `[uiGridViewDelegate numberOfCellsOfGridView:self]` and  `[uiGridViewDelegate numberOfColumnsOfGridView:self]` and look at your console what is printed. You will get an idea where are you going wrong!

Comment: Search [on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjective-c%5D+EXC_ARITHMETIC) and you will find your answer.

Comment: ya u right...for both I am getting zero values.I can I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running a modulo - operation in a c++ function. After some research I found out that there was an issue with division. I started debugging, and yes, I divided by zero... so if anyone will have this issue too, please start debugging and check if you're dividing by zero.